# How to run a program via terminal if it shares its name with another program

Tags: command-line, executable

I have the Ecplise Platform (the programming environment, see https://eclipse.org/) on my system. It can be run by typing "eclipse" into the terminal.

Now I installed eclipse prolog (see http://www.eclipseclp.org/ ). I followed the instructions from http://eclipseclp.org/Distribution/Current/6.1_224_x86_64_linux/Readme.txt ) and now I want to start it. In these instructions they say that it can be run by typing "eclipse" into the terminal.

But if I do that, only the Eclipse programming environment starts, not the eclipse prolog thingy.

What do I do now?

I am using Linux Mint 17, 64 bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figure out where the new `eclipse` is installed, and don't just enter `eclipse` but the full path: `/where/the/new/eclipse/is/installed/bin/eclipse`

If this new eclipse becomes your first choice, you may want to define an alias in your startup files (e.g. `.profile` for `sh`):

```
alias eclipse=/where/the/new/eclipse/is/installed/bin/eclipse
```

Now, if you enter `eclipse`, the new one will be run. To execute the old one, you will have to specify its full path.

You can even define two aliases, one for each `eclipse`:

```
alias eprolog=/where/the/new/eclipse/is/installed/bin/eclipse
alias eplatform=/where/the/old/eclipse/is/installed/bin/eclipse
```

... and enter either `eprolog` or `eplatform` at the shell prompt.

Comment: Or even two aliases, `eprolog` and `eplatform`.

Comment: Ok, the full path works. About the alias: I found a `.profile` file in my home folder and added the line you suggested there. In my case it's `alias eclipse=/mnt/storage/Jana-Daten/Eclipe-Prolog/bin/x86_64_linux/eclipse`. But I still get the Eclipse programming environment opened if I type `eclipse`. And if I choose the alias `eclipse2` instead, the terminal says it could not find the command `eclipse2`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Kjara Find out which shell you're using and modify the proper file. `.profile` is for `sh`, while you could be `bash`, `zsh` or something else, each with there own startup files.

Comment: @Kjara, whichever shell you use, changes to the relevant startup file won't take effect until you source it again, either by logging in in a new terminal, or executing `. .profile` (or other startup file) in the current terminal.

Comment: @Kusalananda Good idea, added to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Kjara If you are using `bash` as your shell of choice, put this in `~/.bashrc` and, like others have said, either open a new terminal, or source it with `source ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

```
export PATH=<path to new eclipse>:$PATH
```

Now when you call eclipse your system will look first for the first path which may contain your executable. As here we prepend the new path it will be checked earlier than whatever is your system's standard PATH variable.

You can add this to the .bashrc or /etc/profile or .profile.